# Odd coprime naturals $u>v$ such that $u-v\mid u+v$. Is it possible that $u-v>2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The question is entirely in the title. I need this result as part of a much bigger question. If this is possible, please give me an example of such $u$ and $v$.

**My progress:**
Let $u=2k+1$ and $v=2l+1$ such that $k>l>0$. Then what we get is
\begin{equation}
k-l\mid 2k+1\qquad\&\qquad k-l\mid 2l+1
\end{equation}
But I can't go any further.

Comment: Have you tried using the condition that $u$ and $v$ are coprime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u,v$ be coprime and $u+v=(u-v)d$. Then $(d-1)u=(d+1)v$.

Thus, $u\mid(d+1)v$, hence $u\mid(d+1)$ and $d+1=uw$ for some $w$.

Similarly, we get $d-1=vw$ (with *the same* $w$!), and $2=(u-v)w$.

This means that $u-v$ *cannot* be greater than $2$.

Comment: Nice but the proof could use another line. That it is the same $w$:  $\{(d-1)u = (d+1)v$;  $d+1=uw$;  $d-1 =vw' \}$ 

$\Rightarrow$ $(vw')u = (uw)v$, 

which gives of course $w'=w$.

Comment: Very good argument, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Assume $u-v>2$. Let $p$ be an odd prime divisor of $u-v$. Then, $p \mid (u+v)$ as well. Adding and subtracting, we can see that $p$ divides $2u$ and $2v$. Since $p$ is an odd prime, this would imply that $p$ divides both $u$ and $v$, which is a contradiction, since they are relatively prime. Thus, there are no odd prime divisors of $u-v$, i.e. it is a power of $2$.

Now, since $u-v>2$ and is a power of $2$, we can see that $4 \mid (u-v)$. Then, we also need $4 \mid (u+v)$. However, adding gives $4 \mid 2u$ which would give $2 \mid u$ and this is a contradiction since $u$ is odd. Thus, we cannot have $u-v>2$ as required.

Comment: Nice argument, thank you very much!